# Getting error while starting hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have no idea what is going on while starting hive in terminal of Ubuntu 17.04, I am getting some error on the terminal. I am new to hive facing some issues with it, can anybody help me on this.

I have (installed and specified in .bashrc file) :

Hadoop : 2.8.0

Hive : 2.1.1

Java : 1.8.0_131

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/local/src/hive-2.1.1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/local/src/hadoop-2.8.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>
> Logging initialized using configuration in
>   jar:file:/usr/local/src/hive-2.1.1/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
>   Async: true Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148) Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.(Hive.java:366)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1654)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not
>   found in metastore. )     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7753)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7731)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.verifySchema(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:565)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:626)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
>     ... 28 more

Comment: How do we check that ?

Comment: Looks like service not running, it says, Unit hive-metastore.service could not be found.

Comment: How can we start that ?

Answer (score 1):

Hive uses a relational database (Derby, MySQL, Postgresql, etc can be configured) to store its metadata.

Let's see a part of your error message:

```
more Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. ) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7753) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7731)
```

Hive tried to verify that the metastore schema version is compatible with Hive binaries that are going to accesss the metastore. In your case, the versions were not incompatible.
See [Hive official documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool) for more detail.

To get thing work, you can:

1) Find the `hive-site.xml` file and configure the property `hive.metastore.schema.verification` is "`false`" so that metastore to implicitly write the schema version if it's not matching.

2) Use [schematool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool) to upgrade the current schema to later version.
See the below link or [Cloudera guide](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_hive_schema_tool.html).